# sending data over RS-232

Tags: c#, .net, serial-port

I have some application that communicates via a RS-232 serial port.

Is there some application or library that I can use to send data to a local serial port?

I need it to be able to locally debug my application.

Comment: You can write such an app in about 20 lines. If you need a specific format then that's likely to be the only way.

Comment: You need to shop for a "virtual null modem".  All the top google hits look good.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If your looking to virtulize a serial port in code, then this will do the trick for you.

http://com0com.sourceforge.net/

As for .NET code, then the "SerialPort" class is incredibly easy to use, a good reference (Iv'e used many times) can be found here.

http://msmvps.com/blogs/coad/archive/2005/03/23/SerialPort-_2800_RS_2D00_232-Serial-COM-Port_2900_-in-C_2300_-.NET.aspx

Using the .NET serial class, you can do what you need in very few lines of code.  Be aware though, you WILL need to use delegates to update your UI.

Answer (score 2):

There are plenty of options when it comes to sending through RS232. Here are some applications that may help you to sent data using RS232:

- RS232 Hex Com Tool -which is a serial software terminal program that can be used to communicate with just about any RS232 peripheral.
- COM Port Data Emulator -it can create a data flow, wrap it to data packets (RS232, TCP/IP or UDP) and send to a port.
- Serial Port Monitor - which also may be helpful with your problem.
  Anyway, its up to you what you will choose. Good luck!

Comment: Please don't post answers on obviously off-topic questions! [See: **Should one advise on off topic questions?**](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/276572/1768232) Off-topic questions can be closed and deleted, which could nullify your contribution. This question is off-topic as it asks for an external resource and will be closed shortly.

Comment: Also please dont approve edits that add random links, especially not if those links are to fishy websites